# Fazer processamento no front-end ou no back-end?

Tags: aplicação-web, lado-do-servidor, single-page-application, lado-do-cliente

Na arquitetura de separação do client-side e do server-side, é comum a dúvida de quem é a responsabilidade de realizar alguns processamentos.

De um lado, processar no client-side pode ser benéfico para a performance do server-side, que se encarrega de entregar o recurso para que seja consumido, formatado e talvez processado no front-end.

Do outro lado, o server-side. Colocar processamento no server-side tem a vantagem de escalar e depender de recursos gerenciados pela própria organização.

#### Contextualizando em REST

Nos princípios da arquitetura REST, o back-end é responsável para a entrega do recurso, por exemplo:

```
GET vnb.rs/api/produtos/1
{
  "nome": "Caneca",
  "variações": [
    {
      "cor": "azul",
      "preço": 15.00
    },
    {
      "cor": "vermelha",
      "preço": 18.00
    }
  ]
}
```

Se eu precisasse do valor mínimo e máximo das variações (de 15,00 a 18,00 reais) dessa caneca, o responsável por esse cálculo seria do front-end ou do back-end?

O que define que tipo de dado pode ser processado no lado do cliente?

Comment: Interessante notar que até poucos anos atrás, o processamento das informações era feito quase que exclusivamente no servidor, pois era difícil o cliente ter uma máquina que suportasse bem o trabalho. Hoje já estamos numa realidade diferente: até smartphones possuem capacidade para realizar funções pesadas, o que permite passar para o cliente boa parte da responsabilidade, salvando recursos do servidor e reduzindo o custo do projeto (*#UseThePlatform*).

Comment: Não tenho uma resposta completa, mas um argumento para favorecer server-side rendering é que as engines de busca só vão conseguir indexar seu site direito se as informações já estiverem no HTML.

Comment: Interessante seu questionamento, @Pedro. Hoje existe o pre-render de páginas, muito útil para indexação de Single-page applications. Essa é a grande dificuldade para os SPAs em geral.

Comment: O que está disponível no lado do cliente :) E talvez essa seja mesmo a resposta, salvo eu não ter entendido a pergunta

Comment: Acredito que em geral quanto mais no lado do cliente melhor, mas há casos em que isso pode mudar, se o sua aplicação é focada para usuários que não possuem máquinas muito potentes, uma ferramenta para ser usada com aplicações pesadas ou você está fazendo um sistema interno para uma empresa sustentável que ainda usa windows xp

Comment: Concordo com o @Guilherme, acho que o nível de responsabilidade referente a processamento no lado do cliente depende muito do negócio e do tipo de aplicação que você quer desenvolver. Se o seu sistema for atender computadores de supermercados que ainda possuem Windows 95, é bom tirar a responsabilidade de processar dados desse caras.

Answer (score 2):

Depende muito do que se propõem a aplicação, mas considerando um sistema criado para web onde a indexação por sites de buscas é basicamente irrelevante (já que é um sistema e não um site), eu uso a seguinte estratégia:

- O back-end fica responsável apenas por responder os requests com dados puros (em json, por exemplo) e realizar o que o back-end sempre faz (validações, processos, manipulação de dados). Ou seja, ele evita montar views dinâmicas.
- Nas views, eu não utilizo loops nem condições em back-end, eu envio o básico (um html com uma chamada de script dentro) e deixo isso para ser montado pelo meu framework javascript, no lado do cliente.

Essa estratégia causam alguns impactos, como:

- O servidor não precisa processar coisas à mais, aliviando os processos (parece que não, mas em gerações de relatórios isso pode ser um diferencial).
- Os dados que trafegam entre servidor e cliente são apenas dados puros, nada de tags e informações que podem ser construídas no cliente. Imagine uma tela com 1000 registros, voltando mil "tr's" e "td's" ao invés de retornar apenas a string dos dados e montar na tela, há um ganho de performance se a internet do cara não ajudar muito.
- Como eu monto tudo no cliente, eu consigo dar um feedback melhor dos processos que estão ocorrendo no cliente. Por exemplo: o cliente me pede um relatório, faço uma requisição no back-end e ai eu consigo informar que estou coletando as informações, quando ela chega, posso informar que estou processando as informações.

O que pode impactar é a performasse do lado do cliente, quando a máquina dele não é boa para processar muitas informações e causa uma lentidão. Mas neste caso seria preciso analisar quantos clientes isso ocorre, se realmente é um grande impacto, qual a frequência que este cliente tem esse problema e etc.

Eu utilizo essa estratégia a alguns anos e já implementei em uma empresa de rastreamento de veículos, onde os relatórios eram gigantescos. Posso lhe dizer que obtive um feedback ótimo por parte, tanto dos clientes, quanto da diretoria. Já que o servidor ficou aliviado de montar views, deixando que processos em paralelo consigam executar mais rapidamente, e os clientes tiveram feedback's melhores do que estava acontecendo na tela.

Comment: Quanto a esse feedback, acredito que não faria diferença entre ele esperar 1s pelo servidor e 1s pela máquina ou 2s pelo servidor (na maioria dos casos), em alguns casos é possível mostrar pequenas partes desses relatórios (ou qualquer outro dado), o que seria interessante, o cliente olha uma parte e quando terminar a próxima já estará pronta