# Construir modelos no PHP ou no JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

A pergunta parece ser obvia, mas gostaria de entender em termos mais técnicos.
Na minha aplicação preciso colocar objetos em um modelo HTML, para visualização do usuário. Tenho duas opções e gostaria de saber qual é a mais eficiente.

1º - Enviar apenas os objetos para requisição AJAX e montar o modelo HTML no JAVASCRIPT e coloca-ló na interface.

2º - Montar o modelo HTML no PHP enviar para requisição AJAX e apenas coloca-ló na interface.

Atualmente estou utilizando a 2º, mas acho que a primeira opção é mais eficiente. Gostaria de saber se estou certo e o motivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa pergunta não tem uma resposta exata como eu disse no meu comentário [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293009/):

*Acredito que em geral quanto mais no lado do cliente melhor, mas há casos em que isso pode mudar, se o sua aplicação é focada para usuários que não possuem máquinas muito potentes, uma ferramenta para ser usada com aplicações pesadas ou você está fazendo um sistema interno para uma empresa sustentável que ainda usa windows xp*

Fazendo uma comparação entre retornar apenas os dados cruciais em formato JSON ou html pronto (dados, tags html, estilos, ...), a primeira vai ser claramente mais rápida porém depende se você quer aliviar o back-end ou o front-end

Mesmo que prefira aliviar o front-end, acredito que vale mais apenas enviar os dados no formato json, e no html criar a tabela, se precisar fazer verificações para, por exemplo, mudar a cor do fundo de cada linha de acordo com um dado específico daquela linha, pode fazer esses `if else`/`switch case` no back-end e retorna o junto com o json a cor daquela linha. O tempo perdido ao enviar mais dados, em geral, não compensa deixar tudo no back

Comment: Esse último paragrafo que você escreveu é justamente o ponto de dúvida, eu montando o card no PHP e retornando, cada objeto já montado no card fica com aproximadamente 1315 caracteres e o retorno sendo apenas o objeto puro ele fica com bem menos caracteres, porém o javascript vai ter o trabalho de estruturar e colocar no seu devido lugar no html. Pelo que você citou não existe um calculo exato de custo ou regra que deva seguir, eu entendi certo ?

Comment: Sim, entendeu. Acredito que minha resposta ficou meio confusa, mas resumindo: aliviar back ou front?, quanto mais dados passados para o front mais demorado, vale a pena deixar tudo pro back? coloque na balança, teste as duas formas e veja qual é a melhor no seu caso

Comment: Tem também a questão de compatibilidade, os navegadores dos seus usuários tem suporte a JS? O mesmo está ativo? Outra coisa que pode interferir é como está seu front, ele já está pesado com vários efeitos de animação ou com alguma outra tarefa?

Comment: Tem suporte sim, a interface está super leve. Eu entendi. Vlw muito obrigado.